# How to stop iOS simulator from prompting me to sign into Apple ID every time it launched my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

Every single time I launch my app, it prompts me to sign into my Apple ID. I can ignore it, but it is incredibly annoying.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

In Settings, I am signed into iCloud. I tried signing in for Media & Purchases but I get this error: "Could Not Sign In - There was a problem connecting to the server."

Comment: It's your app; your code is producing the dialog.

Comment: @matt It's RevenueCat that causes it - good to know thanks

Comment: You can give that as an answer! Might help others.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I was calling a function from the RevenueCat Purchases SDK. This is the function:

```
 Purchases.shared.checkTrialOrIntroductoryPriceEligibility(Array(hashtagsProProductIdentifiersTrialEligibility.keys)) { (result) in
        for key in self.hashtagsProProductIdentifiersTrialEligibility.keys {
            self.hashtagsProProductIdentifiersTrialEligibility[key] = (result[key]?.status != .ineligible)
        }
    }
```

So a hint if you're facing the same issue is check if you are doing any purchasing logic.

Comment: Which version of the Purchases SDK are you using? There were some changes in v3.6.0+ that moved the eligibility check to a local receipt parser which shouldn't trigger any prompt: https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-ios/releases/tag/3.6.0

Comment: Ooo - probably an old version - good call @enc_life - `Purchases (3.1.2)`